# Why is Angular Routing not working on my website?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-routing

I am trying to add angular routing to my website. My website consists of 3 pages:

- index.html (main page)
- home.htm
- contact.htm
- about.htm

I have used w3schools tutorial to set everything up and uploaded everything to my webserver but despite no errors in the console, my content does not display when I change the links. Please look at my HTML and Angular script below:

**INDEX.HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <!-- ... Header data here ... -->
      <!--Angular-->
        <!--Base-->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <!--Roughter-->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="home" ng-controller="homeCtrl" data-ng-init="init()">

    <!--=== Navigation Bar ===-->
        <nav id="nav-bar" class="navbar navbar-default">
              <a id="navbar-brand" href="#/">
                Karly Solis
                <br>
                Multimedia Artist
              </a>
               <!-- ... -->
                <li><a id="option" href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a id="option" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </nav>
    <!--=== /Navigation Bar ===-->

    <div ng-view></div>

    <!-- ======= Footer ======= -->
      <footer>
      </footer>
    <!-- ======= /Footer ======= -->

    <!-- scripts -->
      <script src="angular.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**ANGULAR**

```
    var home = angular.module('home', ["ngRoute"]);

      home.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
          templateUrl : "home.htm"
        })
        .when("/about", {
          templateUrl : "about.htm"
        })
        .when("/contact", {
          templateUrl : "contact.htm"
        })
      });
```

The rest of the pages are body html pages with no header info etc. I will include one of them below for reference.

**About.htm**

```
  <!--=== Form ===-->
    <div id="about" class="container-fluid">
      <div class="page-width">


        <!-- content ... -->


      </div>
    </div>
  <!--=== /Form ===-->
```

I have the file uploaded on to a web server: http://kiawahislandgetaways.com/codingFun/KarlyPortfolio/Website/index.html#/

As of right now nothing shows up on click of any of the links. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Why the downvote? I feel I have done a good job at listing my problem and all important code.

Comment: You still appear to be putting your `home.config(...)` call **inside** the controller function

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally had a clone of the script file and I had updated the wrong version. I have it updated now.

Answer (score 1):

I checked your source code, move config outside the controller,

```
home.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when("/", {
    templateUrl : "home.htm"
  })
  .when("/about", {
    templateUrl : "about.htm"
  })
  .when("/contact", {
    templateUrl : "contact.htm"
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I did this, but still does not seem to display the content.

Comment: Now i dont see the entire route config

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Still i find it inside the controller

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove prefix #  in href tag some thing like below

```html
<li><a id="option" href="about">About</a></li>
<li><a id="option" href="contact">Contact</a></li>
```